# Let $f(z)$ be entire. Suppose $\mathrm{Im} f(x) > 0$ for all $z$. Prove that $f =$ const.

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't know how can I do. A indication is use $L(z)=(iz+1)/(1-iz)$ map the upper half plane into the disk unitary.

Comment: If $f(z)$ is entire then what can we say about $i\cdot f(z)$ and $e^{i\cdot f(z)}$? And what can we conclude about $|e^{i\cdot f(z)}|$?

Answer (score 2):

Composing $f$ with $L$, we obtain
$$L\circ f=z\mapsto \frac{1+if(z)}{1-if(z)}$$
which is an entire function, and takes all values in the unit disk, hence bounded, so it's constant.

Then $f=L^{-1}\circ L\circ f$ is also constant.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to get geometric intuition about the $L$ map, you can also just consider map $g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)+i}$. Since $Im(f(z)) > 0$, we have that $Im(f(z)+i) > 1$, and so $|f(z)+i| > 1$, thus $|g(z)| = \frac{1}{|f(z)+i|} < 1$ for all $z$, and so by Liouville's theorem, it's constant, which also immediately implies that $f(z)$ is constant.